# C# JSON deserialize removing '+'

Tags: c#, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize a JSON object to a model. One of the strings in my object is:

```
mQvhIBYwGVtLQYtoSgUsHBxcvRcRiOpb94zqwYPF8Cz1scPia1pR4BgGZ2ThPv+NhXGlLFK/ZbHy/b3YzjKwBw==
```

I am finding that after RequestFolioDetailModel requestFolioDetailModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(criteria);    within the controller the value of User.SessionId is  removing the '+' and saving the value with a space instead of the '+'.

Just to add this is a MVC Application. I do a Ajax call to the controller passing through a criteria and then serialise it into an object. See code snippets below:

### Code

Javascript function:

```
function GetNotesForCustomer() {    
    var data = {
            FolioId: gModel.SearchPageModel.Body.VfolFolioId,
            User: {
                    SessionId: 'mQvhIBYwGVtLQYtoSgUsHBxcvRcRiOpb94zqwYPF8Cz1scPia1pR4BgGZ2ThPv+NhXGlLFK/ZbHy/b3YzjKwBw=='
                   },
             Note: {
                  Voided: '0'
                   }
               };


    $.ajax({
        url: gBaseUrl + 'Home/SearchCustomerNotes',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: "criteria=" + JSON.stringify(data),
        beforeSend: function () {
            //Do Something
        }, complete: function () {
            //Do Something
        },
        error: function (result) {
          //Do Something
        },
        success: function (result) {    
         //Do Something               
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[Route("Home/SearchCustomerNotes/{criteria?}")]
        public ActionResult SearchCustomerNotes(string criteria)
        {
           ActionResult actionResult;
           RequestFolioDetailModel requestFolioDetailModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestFolioDetailModel>(criteria);   

            // do something with request Folio Detail Model
            return actionResult;
        }
```

Models:

```
    public class RequestFolioDetailModel
        {

            public string FolioId {get; set;}   
            public RequestUserModel User {get; set;}
            public RequestNoteModel Note {get; set;}


            public RequestFolioDetailModel()
            {       
                User = new RequestUserModel();
                Note = new RequestNoteModel();
            }   
        }
    }

public class RequestUserModel
    {
        public string Login {get; set;}
        public string Password {get; set;}
        public string SessionId {get; set;}


        public RequestUserModel()
        {
            Login = string.Empty;
            Password = string.Empty;
            SessionId = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

How do I stop it from doing this as I need the `+` to stay in?

Comment: JSON will not do that.  You're probably seeing URL decoding.

Comment: what's `object`? that code won't compile?

Comment: [I have provided](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4M1lik) a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example that proves JsonConvert is **not** doing what you say it is.  Please edit your question to provide _some_ proof of your claims...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing your JSON from client to server as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content (the default content type for `jQuery.ajax`), but you are not URL encoding it.

The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type requires the body of the request to contain URL encoded key-value pairs separated by `&` characters, just like in a URL query string.  When the MVC server sees this content type, it applies a URL decode operation on each pair in the body, which will cause `+` characters to turn into spaces if the data is not properly encoded.

The quick fix, of course, is to encode your JSON string on the client side just after stringifying it:

```
$.ajax({
    url: gBaseUrl + 'Home/SearchCustomerNotes',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: "criteria=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)),
    ...
});
```

However, since your data is actually JSON, a better solution is to actually send it as `application/json` content and take advantage of the built-in deserialization that the MVC framework provides.  To do this, you need to make a couple of adjustments to your code on both client and server.  On the client side, add a `contentType` specifier to your `ajax` call specifying the data is `application/json`.  Then, remove the `criteria=` part from the data string.  You do not need to do any URL encoding with this content type.  Here is what the client side code would look like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: gBaseUrl + 'Home/SearchCustomerNotes',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    ...
});
```

On the server side, change your method to accept a `RequestFolioDetailModel` object directly.  You can remove the `DeserializeObject` call from the body of the method, since the MVC framework will take care of deserializing the object for you.  And of course, you need to adjust your `Route` attribute to remove the `criteria` part.  You may also want to add `HttpPost` to it while you're at it.

```
[HttpPost, Route("Home/SearchCustomerNotes")]
public ActionResult SearchCustomerNotes(RequestFolioDetailModel requestFolioDetailModel)
{
    // do something with request Folio Detail Model
    ...
}
```